# Connecting pieces of wires- algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I'm using C#, but in the future I might need to use it on other languages.

Many games have such puzzles. There is a group of wires (there are 2 types of wires: straight and curved.), there is a place from where a signal comes and there is a place from where the signal must leave. But the arrangement of the wires doesn't allow that to happen. You must turn some of the wires in order to create a path for the signal.

Yeah, I'm trying to find the continent America again, in order not to try finding it more than once in the future.

Somewhere in the future I will also try the same thing but this time with wires that split the signal to 2 or 3 signals.

Problem is that I can't think of an algorithm that I can imagine how to turn it into a code. I have been thinking for some time and I can't think of anything good.

So, can you help me? I will be able to understand the algorithm as "what does the program has to do", but I basically need help with understanding the algorithm as "how to write the code".

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want? Algorithm that executes the solution (and finds out whether it's correct) or algorithm to solve the puzzle? And what exactly are the rules? Is it similar to the “connect the pipes” games?

Comment: A picture or two would help. And in general, if you know 'what the program has to do', you turn that into code by first breaking it down into actions that do not require human understanding, then translate those actions into code. If you have to think during this second part, you know you haven't done the first part thoroughly enough.

Comment: There's lots of things you need to know about in order to answer this, the only answer is "take a course in programming". Voted to close as it's far too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Union-Find algorithms (that answer my problem) are explained in this PDF file: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/01UnionFind.pdf

I don't think I would have ever thought of this algorithm, let alone making it fast.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at some [maze generation algorithms](http://www.astrolog.org/labyrnth/algrithm.htm) -- they do the same thing you're looking for, and as such are what you'll need to create the grid. Pick a simple 'cell-carver' from the ones I linked to; randomly rotate all of the wire-pieces, et voilà!

A comment on your question notes that turning an algorithm into code involves breaking it down bit by bit -- so that's what we'll do:

You'd start with a grid of potential wire locations (probably 2D, but a 3D game would be amazing).

To produce a solvable level, you could do a couple things -- produce a level, and see if it is solvable (bad), or produce a solved level, then "unsolve" it (better). As I alluded to above, producing a solved level involves algorithms very similar to maze generation -- a solved level would have many traversable "paths", just like a maze. Unsolving the level would just loop through all wire pieces, and rotate them a bit.

But what of maze generation? The resource I linked to contains some algorithms that would be perfect for your use -- a simple randomized DFS should be plenty for your needs.

You'll note that I covered the general case involving branching wires -- as it is, excluding branching means you have to do more coding, to "prune" branches intelligently -- that is, backtracking when your one true path gets stuck, say in a corner, due to the random movement probably necessary to make an interesting level.

You should also note that a solution for such a game would, if I understood correctly, require use of all given wire (I know some games like this). Otherwise, the game would probably be a lot simpler to play given the above generation tactics.

Comment: I needed an idea of how to write the code. I had already made an algorithm when I posted the question, but I couldn't figure out how to connect the wires in the code. But about 2 months ago I found the Union find algorithm that answered my question. YAY! Still, your algorithm is worth keeping in mind, but it doesn't answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: dear me -- I completely misunderstood. Oh well, you're welcome.